# Write a trigger to add a new field on Account to have Name of all closed won opportunity separated by commas?

Tags: soql

How to write a trigger to add a new field on Account to have Name of all closed won opportunity separated by commas??

I wrote the trigger but the functionality won't work. could anyone hlp in it??. here is the code.

```
trigger WonOpp on Opportunity (after insert,after update,before delete)
{
if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate )
{
 list<account> accountlist=[SELECT Id, Name,Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE id in : trigger.new and  StageName='Closed Won')];
 list<opportunity> oppList=[select name from opportunity where accountid in :accountlist and  StageName='Closed Won'];
 map<id,opportunity> OppMap=new map<id,opportunity>(oppList);
for(integer i=0;i<accountlist.size();i++)
  {
     accountlist[i].Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c='';
 for(String key : OppMap.keySet())
 {
   accountlist[i].Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c=OppMap.get(key).name + ','+accountlist[i].Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c;
   }
    }
  update accountlist;
}
if(trigger.isdelete)
{

 list<account> accountlist=[SELECT Id, Name,Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE id in : trigger.old and  StageName='Closed Won')];
 list<opportunity> oppList=[select id,name from opportunity where accountid in :accountlist and id not in :trigger.old and stagename='Closed Won'];
  map<id,opportunity> oppties=new map<id,opportunity>(oppList);
for(integer i=0;i<accountlist.size();i++)
{
  accountlist[i].Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c='';
 for(String key : oppties.keySet())
 {
   accountlist[i].Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c=oppties.get(key).name + ','+accountlist[i].Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c;
  }
    }
    update accountlist;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi user9901 - welcome to SFSE; I took the liberty of quasi- formatting your code using the {} button; please use that in the future.. You should state where functionality doesn't work - as in what results do you get?

Comment: Yes, in general you should specify what it is about your code that does not work. That comes across better than just throwing code in your question and saying "fix it."

Answer (score 0):

You could try selecting the account with it's children oppty records, add the names to a list of strings then use the string.join method to assign them to the field. Something like:

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c, (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won') FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE id in : trigger.new and  StageName='Closed Won')]);
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

for (Account accountRecord : accountList)
{
    List<String> opptyName = new List<String>();
    for (Opportunity accountOppty : accountRecord.Opportunities) {
        opptyName.add(accountOppty.Name);
    }
    if (!opptyName.isEmpty()) {
        accountRecord.Closed_Won_Opportunity_Names__c = String.join(opptyName, ', ');
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountRecord);
    }
}
if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```